# Simulate key presses in C++

Tags: macos

I want my program to press certain keys on my keyboard without me doing it physically.
So I need a subroutine that simulates pressing any key.
What code could I use to accomplish this (Press Any Key) in C++?
(I'm creating a program for MacOSX in Xcode)

Ok I got the mouse sorted now I just need key presses

Comment: Are these events directed to your own app or a different app?

Comment: To where ever is selected/opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use low-level event functions such as `CGEventPost`.  At a higher level, look at the Accessibility APIs, such as `AXUIElementPerformAction`.